# Invalid format when loading jks into keystore

Tags: java, security, keystore, jks

I have a webapp deployed wich uses a jks loaded from a database.

They work perfect on the server but when I run this app on my pc I get an error "Invalid keystore format" at this code:

```
public static KeyStore loadKeystore(InputStream is, String password,String type)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException,
            KeyStoreException {

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(type);
        ks.load(is, password.toCharArray()); //<--error thrown here

        return ks;
    }
```

Both server and I had JAVA 1.6, I installed JAVA 8 on my pc but later returned to 1.6 (changed w7 enviromentals). Could this have something to do? No code was changed.

Im running the webapp from eclipse with this in .ini: C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin

Any idea on what I can try to detect the issue or get it working again?

Thanks

/*how do i read/write*/
--Insert

```
INSERT INTO te_keystores (fields, keystore) VALUES 
(fields, 
decode('/u3+7QAAAAIAAAABAAAAAQA...etc','base64'));
```

--Read with a select field using hibernate

```
<property name="keystore"       type="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType" 
     lazy="true">
     <column name="KEYSTORE" />
 </property>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm looking at an encoding problem?

Comment: How is the keystore stored in the database?

Comment: in postgre, on a bytea field

Comment: And how is it read? Can you post the code (write and read)?

Comment: --Insert
    INSERT INTO te_keystores (fields, keystore) VALUES 
    (fields, 
    decode('/u3+7QAAAAIAAAABAAAAAQA...etc','base64'));  
--Read with a select field using hibernate 
    <property name="keystore"       type="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType" 
      lazy="true">
      <column name="KEYSTORE" />
     </property>

Comment: OK, if I read this correctly you decode your base64 encoded keystore before writing it into the database and there's no dedicated encoding when reading from the db. I think your first idea is right. You have an encoding problem. I suggest to write the base64 encoded data into the db, read it as base64 encoded data and decode it when reading.